# Calendar below footer in mod analytics

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, analytics

Apparently, something went KABOOM on the mod analytics page and I can't get the calendar out of my foot(er). Ouch. See for yourself:

[image: calendar popup at the bottom of the page]

I'm using Chrome 24.0.1312.56 and this picture was taken on GFH.SE [here](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/admin/analytics) (sorry, mods only). It apparently works in Firefox and Opera, but is broken in Chrome on other sites.

It's the same on Programmers (Chrome 24.0.1312.52 m):

[image: calendar popup at the bottom of the page on Programmers]

Comment: Click on the numbers next to `Visited` in your profile, and see if the calendar disappears.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It's still there.

Comment: Kids today are so spoiled. Time was, you got a free calendar in the new year and you said "thank you".'

Comment: Damn, [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)'s default themes sure are ugly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently Chrome allows elements to be placed no further than 2<sup>25</sup> pixels to the left edge of the window*. That's just silly.

Anyway, for the next build I've upgraded our version of jQuery UI to 1.10.0, where this problem has been fixed.

<sub>*at a typical resolution of 96ppi, that's about 8.9 kilometers or 5.5 miles</sub>

Comment: Ha ha ha, Chrome.